# Jquery plugin to show videos from video library in sharepoint 2010

Tags: jquery, video, jquery-ui

I have video library where more than 10 videos have been uploaded. I want to show video list on my page and let user select video to play from that list. any jquery pulgin.? i got some plugin but those were for only youtube videos

Comment: its specific to SharePoint only..!

Comment: It was not clear before, but is more clear now. Although most of the work will probably be adapting an existing plugin to SharePoint lib

Comment: yeah. any idea about any plugin to use here..!?